# How to open a Web URL in a Sharepoint Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a workflow that creates a List Item in a Document Library.

How can I get the workflow to finish writing the List item and then open the webpage of the new list item in a new tab?

Answer (score 1):

Workflows run in the background process on the server, so they cannot send any commands to the browser running on the client computer and thus you cannot open a page in the browser after the workflow finishes some action.

You didn't give us much information about your environment, but in general you would need to change the approach and create that item using some of the client side APIs (REST API or JSOM), instead of the WF, in order to be able to open the item after it has been created.

Comment: Thanks, I’m not competent to use APIs. At the moment, I have used 2 x Custom actions: one to initiate the workflow (to create the new list item), then one to navigate to the URL of the new list item. It’s a bit clumsy and was wondering whether they could somehow be combined